# getting access to ES6 constructor variable

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to access a parameter from a ES6 class without much success. so I have this Animal class that takes a second parameter of foodLevel, and I have a function called setHunger that lowers the food level every second.

I am trying to access the foodLevel in another js file, but I am not sure why I can't get it. in my mind the setHunger function is what I need to call to get that number...

```js
//Animal.js file

export class Animal {
  constructor(name, foodLevel){
    this.name = name;
    this.foodLevel = 10;
  }

  setHunger(foodLevel){
    setInterval(() => {
      this.foodLevel--;
    }, 1000);
  }

};

//Animal interface file

import { Animal } from './../js/animal.js';

$(document).ready(function() {
    
  $('.name').on('click', function(){
    let animalName = $('.animal').val();
    let newAnimal = new Animal(animalName);
    
    var foodLevelOut = newAnimal.setHunger();
    console.log('initial', newAnimal);
     console.log('food', foodLevelOut);
    //debugger;
    //let initialFoodLevel = 10;
    //foodLevelOut = newAnimal.setHunger();

    console.log('foodLevel: 2', foodLevelOut);
  });

  $('.health').click(function() {

  });

});
```

so, in my mind  var foodLevelOut = newAnimal.setHunger(); should get me the foodLevel numbers, but I am getting undefined. appreciate the help.

Comment: Well, `setHunger` doesn't return anything. Functions that return anything *explicitly* return `undefined` *implicitly*. The other questionable choice is `setInterval`: Even if the function returned a value, the value of `foodLevel` would only be updated after one second. However, you seem to want the value to change immediately when you call the function. I guess what you want is `setHunger() { return --this.foodLevel;}`.

Comment: If you're going to include a runnable snippet (and it's a good idea to do so) you should include enough code that it runs. ;-)

Comment: `newAnimal.foodLevel` should give you `10`, before you run `setHunger()`. `setHunger()` just adjusts the `AnimalInstance.foodLevel`, but doesn't return anything, so it returns `undefined`.

Comment: I know you accepted the answer, but using `setInterval` still doesn't make sense to me. Every time the element is clicked you are starting a new interval that reduces the value. I.e. after ten clicks there will be ten intervals running each reducing the value. That doesn't make sense.

Comment: Felix this was just an exercise to learn how it works, is not production code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `setHunger()` doesn't return a value. To access the `foodLevel`, you need to read that property from the class.

jQuery was removed from the snippet for demonstration.

```js
//Animal.js file

 class Animal {
  constructor(name, foodLevel){
    this.name = name;
    this.foodLevel = 10;
  }

  setHunger(foodLevel){
    setInterval(() => {
      this.foodLevel--;
    }, 1000);
  }

};


    let animalName = 'bob';
    let newAnimal = new Animal(animalName);
    
    newAnimal.setHunger();
    
    // The foodlevel is accessed by reading the foodLevel 
    // property of the instantiated Animal class
    console.log('food', newAnimal.foodLevel);
 
    // After 1500 seconds, the foodlevel will have decreased 
    // from the interval in the setHunger() method
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('foodLevel: 2', newAnimal.foodLevel);
    }, 1500)
```

If you want to access the instance from another file, you'll need to export the instantiation.

```
class Animal {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

// Export the class instance
export const animal = new Animal('fred');
```

And in a separate file where you want to access the properties:

```
import {animal} from 'Animal.js';
// animal.name == 'fred';
```

Comment: how can i access newAnimal.foodLevel from a different js file? my question wasn't to clear, but the animal-interface.js file is another file ... that's why I am importing { Animal } ... I tried accessing newAnimal.foodLevel and it just gives me an error because foodLevel is undefined in that file.